# get callbacks on ipsec tunnel in windows xp

Tags: windows, callback, tunnel, ipsec

I want to open an IPsec tunnel from the Windows XP PC (I can do it using MMC GUI) and get callbacks(some Windows API) on the connection status in my application(it can be C, C++ or any other application) like CONNECTION_ESATBLISHED, CONNECTION_FAILED or NEGOTIATION_FAILED.

In other words, I want to know if the tunnel was established, if it's running properly or had being closed through my application code.

I've googled a lot on the subject, but couldn't find any useful information...

Anyone has any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a VPN connection (IPSec) you can configure it with the Remote Access Client API. Create a Ras Entry with RasSetEntryProperties with your IPSec configuration and dial with RasDial. A callback function will notify you about the connection state.